# Level-triggered epoll_wait() on gdb's MI output through pipe doesn't notify the existence of the "(gdb)\n" line

Tags: pipe, epoll

In an application, I spawn gdb and connect its `stdout` (and others) to pipes. I then `epoll_wait` on this pipe (and others) to be notified of when there's a response from gdb.

Every time `epoll_wait` wakes up with a positive return value (there is an fd to read from), I read **one** line from gdb's `stdout` pipe (if that's the fd with an event), and go back to `epoll_wait`.

This all works fine, except sometimes the last line of gdb's response (which is invariably `"(gdb)\n"`) is not read, and `epoll_wait` returns 0 forever. If I wait a few seconds, and then read from gdb's `stdout` pipe despite the fact that `epoll_wait` is returning 0, I can receive the `"(gdb)\n"` line.

What's going on? That data is clearly in the pipe ready to be read from, but the level-triggered epoll is not generating an event for it.

Some notes:

- The pipe connected to gdb's `stdout` is created with `O_NONBLOCK`.
- `epoll_create1` is called with `EPOLL_CLOEXEC` (and nothing else), i.e. it's level triggered.
- I use GNU `getline()` to read a line
- After every call to `getline()`, I `clearerr()` the fd of the pipe (I do this because in a test application I noticed if EOF is reached (because the other end of the pipe hadn't finished writing the whole line before I read it), stdio-based functions get stuck thinking EOF is reached. I can handle reading the line chunk by chunk, so this is fine. I also tried removing the call to `clearerr()` to no effect)
- If I add a one second delay after every line read and before `epoll_wait`ing again, `epoll_wait` will immediately return the `stdout` fd for every line of the initial version+license message, but still not for the last `"(gdb)\n"` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is the buffering that the C standard library does. Here's my guess as to the timeline of events:

- You call `getline`
- `getline` calls `read`
- Two lines are available in the pipe, and `read` returns both of them
- `getline` gives you the first line and buffers the second one
- You call `epoll_wait`
- `epoll_wait` blocks, since the kernel sees there's no data left in the pipe
- `epoll_wait` times out a few seconds later
- You call `getline` again
- `getline` gives you the second line that it buffered earlier

The core problem is that as far as the kernel is concerned, there's no difference between data in the userspace stdin buffer and data that you've already read and processed. To work around the problem, never give the FD to any functions that wrap it in a `FILE *`, and do all of the reading yourself with the `read` syscall directly.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I still can't explain why if I add a delay of 1s between `epoll_wait`s, I still get an event for every line of gdb output (it initially outputs like 20 lines), but perhaps that has just to do with the last line being so short. You're right, I should forego reading through `FILE *`. Thanks